# Scala case class string pattern matching not working as expected?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, string-interpolation

I am using scala 2.13 and have a string like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAtp/Uo28kOjROL50aajnpK25CJoVoic2bqqu6OS2baWWD9fT2
ESqq8mbFxYN3O7JXbs+74YpTdg1jSUALOz9zj/H2eCF71QYvoHmdoi0iiQuy3gS1
6YczVvBvinSwfEnO6Wi/Xx6AC8urdr==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and I want to extract out

```
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAtp/Uo28kOjROL50aajnpK25CJoVoic2bqqu6OS2baWWD9fT2
ESqq8mbFxYN3O7JXbs+74YpTdg1jSUALOz9zj/H2eCF71QYvoHmdoi0iiQuy3gS1
6YczVvBvinSwfEnO6Wi/Xx6AC8urdr==
```

I am using it as follows:

```
val privateKey =
  "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\nMIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAtp/Uo28kOjROL50aajnpK25CJoVoic2bqqu6OS2baWWD9fT2ESqq8mbFxYN3O7JXbs+74YpTdg1jSUALOz9zj/H2eCF71QYvoHmdoi0iiQuy3gS16YczVvBvinSwfEnO6Wi/Xx6AC8urdr==\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"

val result = privateKey match {
  case s"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n$privateKeyB64\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n" => privateKeyB64
  case _ => {
    throw AEMServiceAccountError(s"Invalid RSA Private Key - Please check service account credentials for AEM.")
  }
}
println(result)
```

but the above code always throws `Invalid RSA Private Key - Please check service account credentials for AEM.`

Can someone help me debug what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting the variable outside solves the issue. Not sure why it doesn't work inlined.

```scala
val expectedPrivateKey = s"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n$privateKeyB64\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"

val result = privateKey match {
  case `expectedPrivateKey` => privateKeyB64
  case _ => {
    throw AEMServiceAccountError(s"Invalid RSA Private Key - Please check service account credentials for AEM.")
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm that's wierd... :/ would love an explaination for this from someone

Comment: I would be interested to know as well. I feel like maybe something obvious is staring us in the face and we aren't seeing it. You might try minimizing it to see how simple the string can be and still demonstrate the issue. Along the way you'll probably discover what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps reason is in call unapply in pattern matching. It works with regex

```scala
val regex = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n(.*)\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n".r
val result = privateKey match {
  case regex(privateKeyB64) => privateKeyB64
  case _ => throw AEMServiceAccountError(s"Invalid RSA Private Key - Please check service account credentials for AEM.")
}
```